# CSS rollover help for percentage widths

Tags: css, image, width, percentage, rollover

Does anyone know of a method where I could have a CSS rollover image with a percentage width so that it scales with the size of the page?

I presume that I wouldnt be able to use the method shown here http://www.vision.to/css-only-single-image-fast-rollover.php because that sets the image sprite as the background image.

The only other CSS method I have seen was here: http://thefiles.macadamian.com/2008/06/pure-css-image-rollover-without.html
I like this method but was wondering if it were possible to use one image sprite as opposed to having to load the images separately.

Sorry if I sound very vague, whenever I read these questions I always think the people writing them dont describe what they mean properly and now I've come to do it I'm no better myself haha.
Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do this with sprites. They're done by setting a large image as a background for an element, usually a DIV, and then altering the position so that only the desired portion of the image is shown.  Different DIVs can show different parts of the image by altering the background image position.

However, you can't scale background images. They're always shown at 1:1. You can make them repeat within the element, or not, but you can't scale them, so the sprite idea is out.

Doing it with separate images is fairly straightforward, as indicated by the link you posted.

Preloading an image for rollover is pretty simple. Just include an image tag with the CSS set to hide the image:

```
<img src='myrolloverimage.jpg' style='visibility:hidden; display:none;' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice :)  do you know if it is possible to preload the rollover image? sorry if this is really obvious I am quite new to web design, thanks

Comment: I've added info on preloading to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support IE8 and earlier, you could use the CSS3 `background-size` property with percentage values.

As with foreground images, a sprite file most likely wouldn't be a reasonable option. There are added complexities with sprite files when the image is scaled. The `background-position` is based on the scaled size of the image, and getting an accurate position using percentage values is problematic.